# Magento Naming Convention

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, naming-conventions

Given the class

```
<?php

class NameSpace_HelloWorld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

   public function sayHelloAction()
   {

   }

}
```

What should be the name of the layout file?

```
hello_world.xml
helloworld.xml
```

What should be the xml action name of the sayHelloAction?

```
<hello_world_index_say_hello></hello_world_index_say_hello>
<helloworld_index_sayhello>
```

An article on magento naming conventions would be appreciated. The examples I found only explaned the Namespace_Helloworld_IndexController::sayhello() coding style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What should be the name of the layout file?

Anything you want.  There's no enforced naming convention for the layout file — it's completely decoupled from the module name. All you need to do is specify an XML layout file name in your `config.xml` file.  That said, the convention among the more engineering focused Magento developers is to use a lowercased version of the full module name for third party modules (`namespace_helloworld.xml`).

> What should be the xml action name of the sayHelloAction?

The correct name for this node is the full action handle.  The naming here is going to depend on how you configured your router nodes in `config.xml`, and how a particular URL routed itself through the system.  In other words, beyond the scope of a single Stack Overflow answer.

You can peek at the full action name with the following code in your action method.

```
public function sayHelloAction()
{
    var_dump(strToLower($this->getFullActionName()));
}
```

Generally speaking though, the convention is

```
[Route Name]_[Controller Name]_[Action Name]
```

Assuming you setup your route name to match your module name, that would be

```
route name:      namespace_helloworld
controller name: index
action name:     sayHello
```

or

```
namespace_helloworld_index_sayhello
```

Comment: Correct casing in the handle name.

Comment: Thank you @Alan Storm. Specifying the layout in the config.xml worked. Also helloworld_index_sayhello worked fine inside the xml.Also, thank you for [this article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world). Helped me a lot, although I still hate magento :P

Answer (score 0):

NameSpace_HelloWorld_IndexControllerfile is incorrect controller class name
controller class name should be ended by 'Controller', Controllerfile is not allowed

about layout file: you should define the name of layout file in config.php

about handlers: if you use camelCase, you just need to lowercase the method name and remove 'action' from the end, for example getSuperDataAction will be < route>_< controller>_getsuperdata

Comment: The "file" part was a mistake in the post, not in my code. I fixed that. @Vlamir Fishchenko